# How to reference an offsite web service from code

Tags: c#, wcf, visual-studio, web-services, c#-3.0

I have a .NET code which has a web reference to a web service (eg. WebRef) which resides in a corporate intranet (CorpInt).

The problem is I do not have access to CorpInt from my development machine. And the code has references which goes like

```
WebRef.Customers webref = new WebRefProxy.GetCustomersService();
```

Is there a way in which I could get in the remote intranet site, download something like a disconnected WebRef such that I can compile and reference it on my development machine?

Or any other feasible solution?

thank you in advance.

Comment: Not that I know of. You have to create a dummy service to mimic the intranet one in your development environment, even if it's just to return, again, dummy data.

Comment: so its going to be like I have to create a sandbox web service which returns test values and mimics the methods and return values of the live web service?

Comment: That's pretty much what I have to at work. Most times I work with no access to our servers, so I have to mimic the services. When I'm online, I update my references/endpoints to point to the actual servers. Actually in my csproj, I have some #if blocks for my references.

Answer (score 0):

You shoud try to improve your code design and implement a [Service Stub](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/serviceStub.html), the fundamental objective of this pattern is resolve problems like your:

> Removes dependence upon problematic services during testing